# Debugging SteamCMD/CSGO not updating

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, steamcmd

I'm trying to update my Counter-Strike: Global Offensive server and Steam is giving the error code **0x6** however this error does not seem to be documented anywhere.

```
[...]
Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
Update state (0x3) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
Error! App '740' state is 0x6 after update job.
```

How would I go about finding out what this error means and how to prevent it? My ulimit is **2048**, I have 10GB storage available and everything seems completely fine, networking and everything however SteamCMD just wont update CS:GO.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what I had problems with as well. To update your server you need to use the `force_install_dir` command, because otherwise it won't know where to update something installed with the id 740.

I.E: `force_install_dir ./CSGO/`

(the /CSGO/ is the one where your `srcds_run`, `srcds_linux` and so on are located. (not in the /csgo/ where the actual game-files are)

Answer (score 1):

From memory, error 0x6 means that something in the local SteamCMD file depots is corrupt.

On Linux, you can remove the `~/Steam` directory to (usually) fix it.  I'm not sure where this is located on Windows.

Comment: er... Remove the `/Steam` directory **and then run steamcmd again**.  No idea how I missed that last year.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

My solution was disabling my Steam cache and double checking my network connection to steam (dns, firewall, etc).

Redownload [steamcmd](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) and use the following command:

```
./steamcmd.sh +login anonymous +force_install_dir /$your_serverfiles +app_update 740 validate
```